# Possible to use numba.guvectorize to emulate parallel forall / prange?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, numba, forall

As a user of Python for data analysis and numerical calculations, rather than a real "coder", I had been missing a really low-overhead way of distributing embarrassingly parallel loop calculations on several cores.
As I learned, there used to be the prange construct in Numba, but it was [abandoned because of "instability and performance issues"](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/iOnkSJTcF0A).

Playing with the [newly open-sourced](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/deprecating-numbapro-new-state-accelerate-anaconda) @guvectorize decorator I found a way to use it for virtually no-overhead emulation of the functionality of late prange.

I am very happy to have this tool at hand now, thanks to the guys at Continuum Analytics, and did not find anything on the web explicitly mentioning this use of @guvectorize. Although it may be trivial to people who have been using NumbaPro earlier, I'm posting this for all those fellow non-coders out there (see my answer to this "question").

Answer (score -1):

Consider the example below, where a two-level nested for loop with a core doing some numerical calculation involving two input arrays and a function of the loop indices is executed in four different ways. Each variant is timed with Ipython's `%timeit` magic:

1. naive for loop, compiled using numba.jit
2. forall-like construct using numba.guvectorize, executed in a single thread (`target = "cpu"`)
3. forall-like construct using numba.guvectorize, executed in as many  threads as there are cpu "cores" (in my case hyperthreads) (`target = "parallel"`)
4. same as 3., however calling the "guvectorized" forall with the sequence of "parallel" loop indices randomly permuted

The last one is done because (in this particular example) the inner loop's range depends on the value of the outer loop's index. I don't know how exactly the dispatchment of gufunc calls is organized inside numpy, but it appears as if the randomization of "parallel" loop indices achieves slightly better load balancing.

On my (slow) machine (1st gen core i5, 2 cores, 4 hyperthreads) I get the timings:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 8.19 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 8.27 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 4.6 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 3.46 s per loop
```

Note: I'd be interested if this recipe readily applies to target="gpu" (it should do, but I don't have access to a suitable graphics card right now), and what's the speedup. Please post!

And here's the example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, guvectorize, float64, int64

@jit
def naive_for_loop(some_input_array, another_input_array, result):
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        for k in range(some_input_array.shape[0] - i):
            result[i] += some_input_array[k+i] * another_input_array[k] * np.sin(0.001 * (k+i)) 

@guvectorize([(float64[:],float64[:],int64[:],float64[:])],'(n),(n),()->()', nopython=True, target='parallel')
def forall_loop_body_parallel(some_input_array, another_input_array, loop_index, result):
    i = loop_index[0]       # just a shorthand
    # do some nontrivial calculation involving elements from the input arrays and the loop index
    for k in range(some_input_array.shape[0] - i):
        result[0] += some_input_array[k+i] * another_input_array[k] * np.sin(0.001 * (k+i)) 

@guvectorize([(float64[:],float64[:],int64[:],float64[:])],'(n),(n),()->()', nopython=True, target='cpu')
def forall_loop_body_cpu(some_input_array, another_input_array, loop_index, result):
    i = loop_index[0]       # just a shorthand
    # do some nontrivial calculation involving elements from the input arrays and the loop index
    for k in range(some_input_array.shape[0] - i):
        result[0] += some_input_array[k+i] * another_input_array[k] * np.sin(0.001 * (k+i)) 

arg_size = 20000

input_array_1 = np.random.rand(arg_size)
input_array_2 = np.random.rand(arg_size)
result_array = np.zeros_like(input_array_1)

# do single-threaded naive nested for loop
# reset result_array inside %timeit call 
%timeit -r 3 result_array[:] = 0.0; naive_for_loop(input_array_1, input_array_2, result_array)
result_1 = result_array.copy()

# do single-threaded forall loop (loop indices in-order)
# reset result_array inside %timeit call 
loop_indices = range(arg_size)
%timeit -r 3 result_array[:] = 0.0; forall_loop_body_cpu(input_array_1, input_array_2, loop_indices, result_array)
result_2 = result_array.copy()

# do multi-threaded forall loop (loop indices in-order)
# reset result_array inside %timeit call 
loop_indices = range(arg_size)
%timeit -r 3 result_array[:] = 0.0; forall_loop_body_parallel(input_array_1, input_array_2, loop_indices, result_array)
result_3 = result_array.copy()

# do forall loop (loop indices scrambled for better load balancing)
# reset result_array inside %timeit call 
loop_indices_scrambled = np.random.permutation(range(arg_size))
loop_indices_unscrambled = np.argsort(loop_indices_scrambled)
%timeit -r 3 result_array[:] = 0.0; forall_loop_body_parallel(input_array_1, input_array_2, loop_indices_scrambled, result_array)
result_4 = result_array[loop_indices_unscrambled].copy()


# check validity
print(np.all(result_1 == result_2))
print(np.all(result_1 == result_3))
print(np.all(result_1 == result_4))
```

Comment: Actually your "verification" is wrong because it depends on the number of iterations in ``%timeit``. If the loops deviate then the results will deviate.

Comment: @MSeifert, Your comment does not qualify and shows that you have not even executed the code. By default, %timeit will run the subsequent python expression three times and report the best result. That's fine because Numba compilation time is not the point here.

Comment: Sorry please re-read the comment. You modify the array in-place and you use timeit. So if timeit runs 1000 times the values are ``3*1000*original``. If it runs 100 times they are only ``3*100*original``. Try running your code with ``arg_size = 20``

Comment: @MSeifert : OK you're right in that the final entries in the result vector depend on the number of repetitions done by `%timeit`. The number of repetitions are the same, however, at least for the timing values I stated. To accomodate your concerns I moved the zeroing of the result vector into the `%timeit` call. It doesn't change the message that `numba.guvecorize` enables efficient loop parallelism in python almost trivially.

Comment: Yes very nice answer, just wanted to comment on the validity test, otherwise I found your answer to be very nice and a more use-case example than in the numba documentation. Thank you!

Comment: obsolete since numba 0.36 (numba.prange is back, plus more nice functionality added).